VB Excel obtener huella dactilar y verificarla
Entorno: Digital Persona 4500 con macro VB de Excel.
Quiero ampliar un aplicativo existente para verificar que alguien autoriza la operativa.
Si el lector detecta una huella se activa un control ActiveX y ejecuta el Sub detallado.
Entiendo que "Serialize" está devolviendo una descripción de la huella (que puedo almacenar) y que "Deserialize" hace lo contario y la crea.
He programado crear copia de la huella recibida (Serialize y Deserialize) y pido la verificación entre ambas, pero siempre resulta ser negativa, siendo la misma.
Solicito alguna explicación, seguramente no entiendo algún concepto, soy novato en este tema y si no resuelvo este simple paso no podré programar toda la operativa.
Ni múltiples consultas web ni el manual SDK, me han aclarado conceptualmente que pasa.
Mil gracias a quien me lea.
Private Sub DPFPVerificationControl1_OnComplete(ByVal pFeatureSet As Object, ByVal pStatus As Object)
Dim Fingerprint As DPFPTemplate
Set Fingerprint = New DPFPTemplate
Dim Verification As DPFPVerification
Set Verification = New DPFPVerification
Dim VerificationResult As DPFPVerificationResult
Set VerificationResult = New DPFPVerificationResult
Dim aRawData() As Byte
aRawData = pFeatureSet.Serialize
Fingerprint.Deserialize (aRawData)
Set VerificationResult = Verification.Verify(pFeatureSet, Fingerprint)
If VerificationResult.Verified = True Then
   MsgBox "Coincide"
Else
   MsgBox "Difiere"
   End If
End Sub

